# Opening HTML document from Solution Explorer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to run an HTML file that I have imported into the Solution Explorer. I don't know how to refer to documents in the Solution Explorer in code. How can I do that?

I am currently using this code, but it doesn't work:

```
process.start(".\help.html")
```

Comment: `Process.Run` doesn't exist, so I doubt that could actually be what you've tried.

Comment: sorry minitech i ment process.start

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HTML file to be copied to the output directory. Right-click on your file in the Solution Explorer:

[image: File context menu]

Set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer":

[image: Changing the property]

And finally, just run the file as usual:

```
Process.Start("help.html")
```